# how to speed up my code?

Tags: c, performance, loops, time-complexity

I want to write a bits seggregation code, but I wonder what can I do to increase the speed of the code. Can I get rid of some loops etc?

Aim of code is to seperate 1s and 0s of an array. 0s should be at left and 1s should be at right.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    //code
    int testCase;
    scanf("%d\n", &testCase);

    while(testCase>0) {
        int n;
        scanf("%d\n", &n);
        int countzero = 0;
        while(n>0) {
            int i;
            scanf("%d ", &i);
            if(i==0){
                countzero++;
            }
        }
        for(int i=0; i<countzero; i++) {
            printf("0");
        }
        for(int i=countzero; i<n ; i++) {
            printf("1");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running this code? Once it enters any of your while loops, it has no way of leaving it anymore...

Comment: I forgot decrement testCase. youre right

Comment: Don't forget about `n`, you never change it in the inner `while` loop. Fixing those two things will certainly make the code run faster ;)

Comment: This "Run Snippet" thing is dedicated for HTML/JavaScript. It's useless for C code. (Hence, I removed it.) Look. Now, you have nicely syntax highlighted sample code. IMHO, this looks better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wonder what can I do to increase the speed of the code. Can I get rid of some loops etc?

The time complexity of each test case will be O(n) regardless of what you do, since you have to read all the numbers before you know when you stop printing zeros.

Now, as for speeding up, you can indeed remove at least one loop. Hint: you don't need to count how many zeros there are, only how many ones.